# Pentaho connecting to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I am working on Pentaho Data Integration tool version 7.1. I am trying to connect to a database using 'Table Input' step. but when I test the connection in this step in Pentaho it is giving me the below error message. I am able to connect to DB using the MySQL workbench (MySQL is 5.7). I have placed the 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar' file in the lib folder. My Java is 1.8.0-131; I am using Windows 10.

Error connecting to database [mydb] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Unknown database 'mydb'

Comment: Did you create a connection on pentaho?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `pentaho` version supports mysql connector .if it is not, download the required version and paste -> extract the file and paste it in the

> \pdi-ce-8.2.0.0-342\data-integration\lib
>
> After that open spoon.bat goto menu ->tool->marketplace ->install
>   mysql plugin

Restart pentaho after installing mysql plugin.
then try connecting to mysql .Hope it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JDBC does not find your database. It may come from a typing mistake in the name, password, that the user has not enough grant,...

To debug use the test button on the bottom of the new connection button:

[image]